# Can I make git smarter when figuring out if it's okay to delete a branch?

Tags: git, merge, branch

`git branch -d` is almost always wrong about if a branch has code I haven't merged. Very often I'll have branched **foo** off of **master**, done work, and then merged it back into **master**, but then `git branch -d` says "The branch 'foo' is not fully merged", until I merge master back into foo (which is sometimes a pain).

Comment: once you have merged a branch you should not receive this message. git checks if all commits of branch foo are reachable from branch master. it only complains if there are new (unmerged) commits in foo. what version of git are you using? can you post a simple testcase to reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should not have to merge something into **foo** to be able to delete **foo**.

As far as I experienced, the criterion is whether ***foo*** is merged into **HEAD**, so maybe you should make sure **master** is your current branch when trying to delete **foo**.

Comment: Yes, I am certain of that. It's possible that the branch i question was merged into a **bar**, which was then merged into **master**… I figured git should be smart enough to see that those changesets exist in master.

Comment: Hmm actually in this case it looks like i squashed **foo**'s commits, so they had different refs. But I'm pretty certain the scenario I've described above has happened.

Comment: Look with `gitk` or `git log` or something, whether the tip of **foo** is reachable from your current head.

Answer (score 1):

> in this case it looks like i squashed `foo`'s commits

That would be consistent with the "isn't fully merged" warning (branch with  commits that are not reachable from any other ref head)

Two checks can be done:

1/ The "[Git and “`The branch 'x' is not fully merged`” Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548926/git-and-the-branch-x-is-not-fully-merged-error)" question is interesting:

```
git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline master...foo
```

2/ See "[Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)"

```
git branch --contains branch-to-delete
```

More than one branch should be returned

Answer (score 0):

Do a

```
git rebase master foo
```

after you have merged everything. Then a `git branch -d foo` should succeed

Answer (score -5):

```
#!/bin/sh
# Get rid of all the branches I don't care about.

for b in $(git branch) ; do
  git rebase master ${b}
  if test $? -ne 0; then git rebase --abort ; fi
  git checkout -f master
done

for b in $(git branch) ; do git branch -d ${b} ; done
```

Comment: This is a really bad idea - you don't really *ever* want to blindly rebase all your branches.