# Git "error: The branch 'x' is not fully merged"

Tags: git, git-branch

Here are the commands I used from the master branch

```
git branch experiment
git checkout experiment
```

Then I made some changes to my files, committed the changes, and pushed the new branch to GitHub.

```
git commit . -m 'changed files'
git push -u origin experiment
```

Later on I decided to merge my experiment branch into the master branch.

```
git checkout master
git merge experiment
```

Finally I pushed the changes to GitHub.

```
git push -u origin master
```

All went well until I tried deleting my experiment branch using

```
git branch -d experiment
```

I got the error message:

> error: The branch 'experiment' is not fully merged.
> If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D experiment'.

I'm a bit new to git, and I don't know how much more I could possibly merge the two branches. What am I missing here?

Comment: Does this post help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others

Comment: This comes up sometimes when I've done a `git commit --amend`

Comment: Also - Be mindful that this message will appear after a `squash`: https://stackoverflow.com/q/41946475/109941

Comment: I think the most common scenario is, you just need to pull your newly merged changes before you delete the branch locally.

Answer (score 429, accepted):

<sup>**Note** Wording changed in response to the commments. Thanks @slekse</sup>

That is not an error, it is a warning. It means the branch you are about to delete contains commits that are not reachable from any of: its upstream branch, or HEAD (currently checked out revision). *In other words, when you might lose commits¹.*

In practice it means that you probably amended, rebased (including squash merge) or filtered commits and they don't *seem* identical.

Therefore you could *avoid the warning* by checking out a branch that does contain the commits that you're about *un-reference* by deleting that other branch.²

You will want to verify that you in fact aren't missing any vital commits:

```
git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline master...experiment
```

This will give you a list of any nonshared between the branches. In case you are curious, there might be a difference without `--cherry-pick` and this difference could well be the reason for the warning you get:

> `--cherry-pick`
>
> Omit any commit that introduces the same change as another commit on the "other side" when the set of commits are limited with symmetric difference. For example, if you have two branches, A and B, a usual way to list all commits on only one side of them is with --left-right, like the example above in the description of that option. It however shows the commits that were cherry-picked from the other branch (for example, "3rd on b" may be cherry-picked from branch A). With this option, such pairs of commits are excluded from the output.

---

¹ they're really only garbage collected after a while, by default. Also, the `git-branch` command does not check the revision tree of *all branches*. The warning is there to avoid obvious mistakes.

² (My preference here is to just force the deletion instead, but you might want to have the extra reassurance).

Comment: Thanks. The key phrase was "contains commits that are not reachable from any other ref head". Even though I no longer needed the experiment branch, and had already merged it into master, and planned on deleting it from origin, git wasn't going to be happy until I'd pushed the changes to experiment to origin. I guess this warning was a sanity check of sorts.

Comment: -1 "It means the branch you are about to delete contains commits that are not reachable from any other ref head." This is not correct. The warning means that the branch is not reachable from either its upstream (if it has one), or from the current HEAD. See manpage of git-branch.

Comment: @sleske +1 I was allowed to delete the branch after I pushed the repo.

Comment: @TachyonVortex Nice link.  The command  git branch -vv really clarified what was going on for me.

Comment: @sleske Thanks for the comment -- this answer should really be edited. It's a shame it is s highly upvoted because the main explanatory sentence is incorrect. I just had this problem and spent an annoyingly long time trying to figure out what the problem was, and it was just that the remote tracking branch had been deleted as part of the pull request, and in the time since I had pulled changes from master on the local branch. The only 'problem' was not finding the remote tracking branch, which was deleted (and I was trying to delete the local branch for the same reason).

Comment: Yeah, this can happen merely when attempting to delete a local branch if you're on a different branch than the one you were on when you created it. "Commits that are not reachable from any other ref" is incorrect and needlessly scary!

Comment: What's the difference between `..` and `...`? The latter appears in the answer, but the former seemed to be more helpful in my case.

Comment: @Dror and you'll find [`man git-rev-parse`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html#_specifying_ranges) even more helpful! In short, `...` compares _both ways_, i.o.w. it doesn't assume only the right side can contain unique commits.

Comment: @sleske and others: Finally came round to testing this again and tightening up the wording. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: The key is that the side-branch must be fully merged in the **current** branch. I had a branch X' from X fully merged back into X and had already deleted origin/X'. But with Y checked out I got this warning. When I checked out X I was able to delete X'. It's rather stupid, I think.

Comment: -1: Why "warning"? First of all, it reads: "error: The branch 'trial' is not fully merged." Second, warnings don't prevent the operation they warn about. That's their definitive difference from errors. This one does. This looks like an error, acts like an error, so why do you call it a warning?

Comment: @Sz. It's a safety warning. You can override it. So the safety is what promotes it to an "error", it's only a paradox, not a contradiction. It's GOOD that git decided to treat the safety warning as an error. But logically it is warning the user of a regular situation that normally occurs. When I said "that's not an error" I was responding to the OP in the sense that it "is not something you are doing wrong"

Comment: *This will give you a list of any nonshared between the branches.* Since it is a two way compare, how do I know from which branch the listed commits are missing?

Comment: @kerner1000 have you tried it yet? The  `--left-right` option marks each commit with `<` or `>`. Recent git supports `--cherry-mark` as well to also show the shared commits

Comment: @sehe, yes, trying it. It seems to be inverted, though.. `--left-right [] develop...issue` shows me commits marked with `<` but those are in develop for sure.

Comment: That git isn't checking every branch is IMHO a bug. Either warn when it's a true and accurate warning, or never warn. Warning when it's sometimes true and sometimes not isn't helpful.

Comment: @studog because of that bug I could commit to wrong branch. I created scenario where that bug can cause pushing to wrong branch. https://gist.github.com/quant61/1fb8e2c0236a74bfe8b42cee9ae2849e

Comment: @kerner1000 < marks the commits that exist in the lefts side, so yes those are in develop.

Answer (score 113):

As Drew Taylor pointed out, branch deletion with -d only considers the *current* HEAD in determining if the branch is "fully merged".  It will complain even if the branch *is* merged with some other branch.  The error message could definitely be clearer in this regard...
You can either checkout the merged branch before deleting, or just use git branch -D.  The capital -D will override the check entirely.

Comment: The part about current HEAD fixed it for me. My master was different from the feature branch of of which I created the conflicting branch :D

Comment: For someone learning git, the word "current" seems redundant with "HEAD"?  There is no such thing as a uncurrent HEAD -  the HEAD by definition *is* the *current* branch. Am I missing something? I suppose you could say "current branch" or "HEAD" but not "current HEAD".

Comment: Is there any way to change/configure this (e.g., have it always check against `origin/master`?) I guess checking out `origin/master` first isn't too onerous, but it just feels like a kind of weird flow -- why do I need to check out `origin/master` locally just for you to verify that my changes are merged there?

Comment: @Alec you can always create an alias. There's nothing special about `master`. git makes no assumptions (or requirements) about branch names or importance, it's up the the user to be explicit about what we want merged/compared/checked etc. git doesn't even assume that the remote `master` is more important that your local branches! And to be clear, `origin/master` is your local copy of the remote `master` at `origin`, which may or may not be the same as your local `master` (depends if you did a fetch or pull). You checkout `master`. There's rarely a good reason to checkout `origin/master`.

Comment: @Zim On any shared project I avoid having a local master branch, I always use origin/master (if you care: https://alecb.me/dont-checkout-master)

Comment: _"checkout the merged branch before deleting."_ It seems not possible to delete the branch that is currently checked out.

Comment: I don’t think you can delete checked out branches

Answer (score 34):

I tried sehe's answer and it did not work.

To find the commits that have not been merged simply use:

```
git log feature-branch ^master --no-merges
```

Answer (score 19):

**Easiest Solution With Explanation (double checked solution) (faced the problem before)**

Problem is:

1- I can't delete a branch

2- The terminal keep display a warning message that there are some commits that are not approved yet

3- knowing that I checked the master and branch and they are identical (up to date)

solution:

```
git checkout master
git merge branch_name
git checkout branch_name
git push
git checkout master
git branch -d branch_name
```

Explanation:

when your branch is connected to upstream remote branch (on Github, bitbucket or whatever), you need to merge (push) it into the master, and you need to push the new changes (commits) to the remote repo (Github, bitbucket or whatever) from the branch,

what I did in my code is that I switched to master, then merge the branch into it (to make sure they're identical on your local machine), then I switched to the branch again and pushed the updates or changes into the remote online repo using "git push".

after that, I switched to the master again, and tried to delete the branch, and the problem (warning message) disappeared, and the branch deleted successfully

Answer (score 16):

I had this happen to me today, as I was merging my very first feature branch back into master. As some said in a thread elsewhere on SO, the trick was switching back to master before trying to delete the branch. Once in back in master, git was happy to delete the branch without any warnings.

Comment: This is a different warning, without the ‘is not fully merged’.

Answer (score 5):

You can simply figure out :

> git log --cherry master...experimental

`--cherry` option is a synonym for `--right-only --cherry-mark --no-merges`

git-log man page said

> it's useful to limit the output to the commits on our side and mark those that have been applied to the other side of a forked history with git log --cherry upstream...mybranch, similar to git cherry upstream mybranch.

FYI. `--cherry-pick` omits equivalent commits but `--cherry-marks` doesn't. It's useful to find rebase and force updated changes between upstream and co-working public branch

Comment: This worked, I did a pull request on the github site, on the github site it was shown as if 1 commit ahead, but that commit was already in the main branch. Also `git branch -d -r origin/branch-name` works strangely, it supposedly deletes, but it is still on remote, and second time it shows as not found.

Answer (score 5):

Git is warning that you might lose history by deleting this branch. Even though it would not actually delete any commits right away, some or all of the commits on the branch would become unreachable if they are not part of some other branch as well.

For the branch `experiment` to be “fully merged” into another branch, its tip commit must be an ancestor of the other branch’s tip, making the commits in `experiment` a subset of the other branch. This makes it safe to delete `experiment`, since all its commits will remain part of the repository history via the other branch. It must be “fully” merged, because it may have been merged several times already, but now have commits added since the last merge that are not contained in the other branch.

Git doesn’t check every other branch in the repository, though; just two:

1. The current branch (HEAD)
2. The upstream branch, if there is one

The “upstream branch” for `experiment`, as in your case, is probably `origin/experiment`. If `experiment` is fully merged in the current branch, then Git deletes it with no complaint. If it is not, but it is fully merged in its upstream branch, then Git proceeds with a warning seeming like:

```
warning: deleting branch 'experiment' that has been merged
to 'refs/remotes/origin/experiment', but not yet merged to
HEAD.
Deleted branch experiment (was xxxxxxxx).
```

Where `xxxxxxxx` indicates a commit id. Being fully merged in its upstream indicates that the commits in `experiment` have been pushed to the origin repository, so that even if you lose them here, they may at least be saved elsewhere.

Since Git doesn’t check other branches, it may be safe to delete a branch because you know it is fully merged into another one; you can do this with the `-D` option as indicated, or switch to that branch first and let Git confirm the fully merged status for you.

Comment: The key is "fully merged in the **current** branch". I had a branch X' from X fully merged back into X and had already deleted origin/X'. But with Y checked out I got this warning. When I checked out X I was able to delete X'. It's rather stupid, I think.

Comment: This answer is plagiarized from here without attribution http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1230000000561/ch05.html#branch-deletion

Answer (score 3):

to see changes that are not merged, I did this:

```
git checkout experiment
git merge --no-commit master

git diff --cached
```

*Note: This shows changes in `master` that are not in `experiment`.*

Don't forget to:

```
git merge --abort
```

When you're done lookin.

Answer (score 2):

I did not have the upstream branch on my local git.  I had created a local branch from master, git checkout -b mybranch .  I created a branch with bitbucket GUI on the upstream git and pushed my local branch (mybranch) to that upstream branch.  Once I did a git fetch on my local git to retrieve the upstream branch, I could do a git branch -d mybranch.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the flag `--force` is what you are really looking for. Just use `git branch -d --force <branch_name>` to delete the branch forcibly.

Answer (score 0):

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ember-roomviewer>git branch -d guided-furniture
warning: not deleting branch 'guided-furniture' that is not yet merged to
         'refs/remotes/origin/guided-furniture', even though it is merged to HEAD.
error: The branch 'guided-furniture' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D guided-furniture'.
```

The solution for me was simply that the feature branch needed to be pushed up to the remote. Then when I ran:

```
git push origin guided-furniture
/* You might need to fetch here */
git branch -d guided-furniture

Deleted branch guided-furniture (was 1813496).
```

Answer (score 0):

If you made a merge on Github and are seeing the error below. You need to pull (fetch and commit) the changes from the remote server before it will recognize the merge on your local. After doing this, Git will allow you to delete the branch without giving you the error.

> error: The branch 'x' is not fully merged.
> If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D 'x'.

Answer (score 0):

The accepted answer is correct. In this answer, I will add three things:

1. how this has happened (often to me)
2. show an example
3. how to make sure you are not missing any changes before force delete via `-D`

I use **Rebase and merge** on GitHub as the default PR merging approach. That creates **new** commit (hashes) for the same changes.

For example, when I run

```
git log --graph --left-right --oneline add-theme-dark-2...main
```

on one of my project, I got this:

```
> fba6fce (HEAD -> main, tag: v2.0.9, origin/main) Refactored to semantic class names.
> 4e665bc Refactored to semantic class names. (1a)
....
> 8bd13a6 Added 'font-semibold' to title.     (2a)
< 23f7b8a (add-theme-dark-2) Refactored to semantic class names.
< cf71814 Refactored to semantic class names.  (1b)
....
< d3a774a Added 'font-semibold' to title.      (2b)
(END)
```

Note how 1a/1b and 2a/2b have different commit hashes.

To make sure that you are not missing changes, run:

```
git log --graph --left-right --cherry-pick --oneline add-theme-dark-2...main
```

If it return a list, that each line start with "=":

```
= fba6fce (HEAD -> main, tag: v2.0.9, origin/main) Refactored to semantic class names.
= 4e665bc Refactored to semantic class names.
...
= 346770b Moved text size to component.
= 68cd471 Added theme-dark.
= 8bd13a6 Added 'font-semibold' to title.
```

it is safe to delete the branch with:

```
git branch -D add-theme-dark2
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case , this happened because the branch had no commits. It had only been created from another branch.

The solution: Make 1 commit in the branch. Then I could switch to another branch and delete it, with no error.