# "git branch -d" doesn't delete branch

Tags: git

I merged a branch in master a few days ago. I didn't make any changes in the branch, but when I tried to delete it today with `git branch -d branch_name` it said the branch isn't fully merged in.

I got curious and did a `gitg` and saw that there was a stash in the branch. So I thought may be that stash is causing that behavior. I deleted the stash. But still I get the same error.

Doing a git status doesn't show any changes.

I can delete the branch using `git branch -D branch_name`.

1. Why isn't `-d` working?
2. How can I see what is not merged in? (`gitg` doesn't show anything.)

Comment: please post a log excerpt, something like `git log --oneline --graph --decorate master <OTHERBRANCH>`, and post the part from just before the merge you mentioned

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7548926/git-and-the-branch-x-is-not-fully-merged-error

Comment: What's the result of `git log ..branch_name`?

Comment: I was about to post what @gcbenison just posted. That command will tell you commits are unique to that lineage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that you have commits on the branch that you are trying to delete that are not in the branch that you are currently one.

`git diff <branch you are one> <branch you are deleting>`

should show what is not merged in (in diff format).

[As this answer says](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1710951/498699) doing `git branch --contains branch-to-delete` should show the commits that are not merged.