# git: why can't I delete my branch after a squash merge?

Tags: git, merge, git-merge

I have a git repo with `mainline` (equivalent to `master`) and some local feature branches.  For example:

```
$ git branch
* mainline
  feature1
  feature2
  feature3
```

When I do the following, I am able to squash merge all of my edits in a feature branch into one commit to `mainline`:

```
$ git checkout mainline
$ git pull
$ git checkout feature1
$ git rebase mainline
$ git checkout mainline
$ git merge --squash feature1
$ git commit
$ git push
```

My question is, at this point, when I try to delete the `feature1` branch, it tells me it is not fully merged:

```
$ git branch -d feature1
error: The branch 'feature1' is not fully merged.
If you are sure you want to delete it, run 'git branch -D feature1'.
```

What causes this error? I thought `git merge --squash feature1` merged `feature1` into `mainline`.

Answer (score 103, accepted):

This happens because Git doesn't know that the squash merge is "equivalent to" the various branch-specific commits.  You must forcibly delete the branch, with `git branch -D` instead of `git branch -d`.

(The rest of this is merely about *why* this is the case.)

#### Draw the commit graph

Let's draw (part of) the commit graph (this step is appropriate for so many things in Git...).  In fact, let's step back one more step, so that we start before your `git rebase`, with something like this:

```
...--o--o--o     <-- mainline
      \
       A--B--C   <-- feature1
```

A branch *name*, like `mainline` or `feature1`, points only to one specific commit.  That commit points back (leftward) to a previous commit, and so on, and it's these backward pointers that form the actual branches.

The top row of commits, all just called `o` here, are kind of boring, so we didn't give them letter-names.  The bottom row of commits, `A-B-C`, are *only* on branch `feature1`.  `C` is the newest such commit; it leads back to `B`, which leads back to `A`, which leads back to one of the boring `o` commits.  (As an aside: the leftmost `o` commit, along with all earlier commits in the `...` section, is on *both* branches.)

When you ran `git rebase`, the three `A-B-C` commits were *copied* to *new* commits appended to the tip of `mainline`, giving us:

```
...--o--o--o            <-- mainline
      \     \
       \     A'-B'-C'   <-- feature1
        \
         A--B--C       [old feature1, now abandoned]
```

The new `A'-B'-C'` commits are mostly the same as the original three, but they are *moved* in the graph.  (Note that all three boring `o` commits are on both branches now.)  Abandoning the original three means that Git usually doesn't *have* to compare the copies to the originals.  (If the originals had been reachable by some other name—a branch that appended to the old `feature1`, for instance—Git *can* figure this out, at least in most cases.  The precise details of how Git figures this out are not particularly important here.)

Anyway, now you go on to run `git checkout mainline; git merge --squash feature1`.  This makes one new commit that is a "squash copy" of the three—or however many—commits that are on `feature1`.  I will stop drawing the old abandoned ones, and call the new squash-commit `S` for Squash:

```
...--o--o--o--S         <-- mainline
            \
             A'-B'-C'   <-- feature1
```

#### "Delete safety" is determined entirely by commit history

When you ask Git to delete `feature1`, it performs a safety check: "is `feature1` merged into `mainline`?"  This "is merged into" test is based purely on the *graph connectivity*.  The name `mainline` points to commit `S`; commit `S` points back to the first boring `o` commit, which leads back to more boring `o` commits.  Commit `C'`, the tip of `feature1`, is *not* reachable from `S`: we're not allowed to move rightward, only leftward.

Contrast this with making a "normal" merge `M`:

```
...--o--o--o---------M   <-- mainline
            \       /
             A'-B'-C'    <-- feature1
```

Using the same test—"is the tip commit of `feature1` reachable from the tip commit of `mainline`?"—the answer is now *yes*, because commit `M` has a down-and-left link to commit `C'`.  (Commit `C'` is, in Git internal parlance, the *second parent* of merge commit `M`.)

Since squash merges are not actually *merges*, though, there is no connection from `S` back to `C'`.

Again, Git doesn't even *try* to see if `S` is "the same as" `A'`, `B'`, or `C'`.  If it did, though, it would say "not the same", because `S` is only the same as the *sum* of all three commits.  The only way to get `S` to match the squashed commits is to have only one such commit (and in this case, there's no need to squash in the first place).

Comment: So is there no better solution than just manually tracking which branches you've merged?

Comment: @Alec: With squash merges, generally the correct thing is to *delete* the branch you've just merged, losing all the commits you've just traded in for a single squash-commit. In other words, if we've already discarded `A-B-C` in favor of `A'-B'-C'` and we're now using `S` in favor of `A'-B'-C'`, we should discard `A'-B'-C'` too—and the name `feature1` can go into the rubbish bin with them, and in fact, tossing the feature branch name is *how* they all go away. If we do this all in one big lump sum process, we're fine. If we do it piecemeal, then yes, you have to track everything carefully.

Comment: @torek That feels like a cumbersome workflow, especially when using GitHub. You merge a PR with a squash commit, but then you need to remember to go delete the branch. If you forget, there's no way  for git to tell you which of your branches can be safely deleted.

Comment: @Alec: I agree; but I think squash merge should *never* be used except by whoever is writing the code in the first place, and hence is in control of the branch.

Comment: @torek After all, do you recommend to do the squash in the feature branch instead and then follow up with a merge or rebase-merge ?

Comment: @thanos.a: that flow makes lots of sense. But in general I don't use squash directly: if I have some set of commits that I think have a good result, but the individual commits need cleanup, I use interactive rebase (or the manual equivalent of this) to do the cleanup. This leaves me with N (usually N > 1) commits, each of which is a good standalone commit, where all N of them implement the feature and can now be merged.

Answer (score 20):

You can in fact determine and delete squash-merged branches, though it is non trivial.

```
git for-each-ref refs/heads/ "--format=%(refname:short)" | while read branch; do mergeBase=$(git merge-base master $branch) && [[ $(git cherry master $(git commit-tree $(git rev-parse $branch\^{tree}) -p $mergeBase -m _)) == "-"* ]] && git branch -D $branch; done
```

To determine if a branch is squash-merged, git-delete-squashed creates a temporary dangling squashed commit with [git commit-tree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit-tree). Then it uses [git cherry](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry) to check if the squashed commit has already been applied to master. If so, it deletes the branch.

All credits go to Teddy Katz, https://github.com/not-an-aardvark/git-delete-squashed

Comment: Very interesting, but I'd be somewhat afraid to use such an automatic procedure; also, the main reason why I squash commits is just because I want to get rid of the intermediate commits on a topic branch, so why shouldn't I simply delete the branch after merging it?