# Git: Merging in reverse direction after squashed merge

Tags: git, merge, version-control, git-merge

My team is using a Gitflow-like workflow, but a recent merge from `develop` to `master` for a release was unintentionally done as a squash merge.  At the time, we didn't raise any alarms and figured we'd get it right next time, but then we had to do a hotfix off of that release.  Now, we need to get that hotfix merged back into `develop`, which has since diverged from `master`.  We're getting conflicts, some legitimate, but most of them noise due to git thinking that the squash-merge commit on `master` represents its own separate commit of the changes, rather than a merge from `develop`.

A graph may help illustrate the issue:

```
 A ---------- D -- G (master)
  \
   \- B -- C -- E -- F (develop)
```

In this case, `D` is the result of a squash-merge of B and C (instead of a regular merge, as we would have normally done).  Note that `git diff C D` returns empty - i.e. they are identical in content.

Now, I want to merge `master` into `develop`; I expect some conflicts due to legitimate overlap between `E`, `F`, and `G` (hence I can't simply globally say "use ours" or "use theirs").  But I'm getting conflicts for basically everything in `B`, `C`, and `D`, presumably because git views `D` (understandably) as its own commit in a separate chain of commits on `master` starting from A.

Long story short, what I'm hoping for is something like "merge relative to these two identical commits (`C` and `D`)" rather than "merge relative to `A`".  Sort of like `rebase --onto`, but for merging, I guess.

FWIW, I know that I can just resolve the conflicts by hand; I'm just curious if there's a way to skip all the garbage conflicts introduced by having done a squash-merge instead of a regular merge when `D` was created.

Comment: just checkout master and git merge --ours C to recreate the missing merge history

Comment: @AndrewC That would also work; I was trying to avoid creating an unnecessary commit on `master` but that seems like a decently clean way to do it.  As it turns out, we determined that we could get by without the hotfix changes on `develop`, so we ended up doing `git merge -s ours master` from `develop` and all was well.  Still interested to see if there are other ways to solve this problem (like yours) *without* simply dropping the changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATE** - I had forgotten important information about exactly how this works; fixed.

---

For now I'll assume that doing a history rewrite (and the subsequent clean-up) isn't really a practical solution...

In this specific case, the simplest hack would be to use `git replace` during the merge.  This *would not work* if not for the fact that `C` and `D` have the same content.

In a clone you can say

```
git replace --graft <E> <D>
```

(where `<E>` and `<D>` are expressions that resolve to the corresponding commits; in the above example, this might be `git replace --graft develop^ master^`).  This creates a new commit `E'` that "looks like" `E`, but its parent is `D`.  It then uses `E'` as a replacement for `E` - so when an operation leads git to `E`, it still sees `E`s commit ID, but it gets the rest of its info about that commit from `E'`.  Physically you have

```
                E'
               /
 A ---------- D -- G (master)
  \
   \- B -- C -- E (REPLACE:E')
                 \
                  F (develop)
```

So then you

```
git chekcout develop
git merge master
```

(or maybe `git merge hotfix-branch` but you didn't show that in your graph, so we'll go with the simplified example)...  Now the `merge` command "sees"

```
A ---------- D -- G (master)
              \
               (E|E') -- F (develop)
```

so it uses `D` as the merge base.  Because `C` and `D` have the same content, the calculated merge result is what it should be.  The result "looks like"

```
A ---------- D ------------ G (master)
              \              \
               (E|E') -- F -- M (develop)
```

which is really

```
                E'
               /
 A ---------- D ------ G (master)
  \                     \
   \                F -- M (develop)
    \              /
     \- B -- C -- E (REPLACE:E')
```

Now the history around `D`..`M` "looks funny", and that's the down side of doing this (rather than a history correction to replace `D` with a true merge).  `M` is a borderline "evil merge", but since the default merge would conflict anyway (and since the calculated result is the "natural" resolution of the conflict) it's not terrible.

Once this is done you no longer need the replacement.  Future merges between `master` and `develop` will see `G` as the merge base anyway, so the messiness that precedes it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I wasn't familiar with `git replace`.  It's not working exactly as you described here, however - for some reason, it's finding the merge base as `A`, which means I still have conflicts related to `B`/`C`/`D`.  Interestingly, if I do `git merge-base` *without* `git replace`, it actually finds the last commit from `develop` that was merged into `master` to create `A` (not shown in my example).

Comment: Hmm... retested, and I agree, this will not work as I indicated.  Which is strange, because I'm pretty sure I've used this technique before.  But in current tests at least, the replacement object is shown but with the original ID; which means it won't be seem as "the same" by merge-base.  I'm going to delete this answer for now, and will re-post if further investigation refines this to a form that works.

Comment: This version should work.  The "illusion" of a replacement isn't complete at the replaced commit itself, but only at its parent; so instead of directly replacing the commit that's identical (`C`) with `D`, you need to replace its child (`E`) with a hypothetical commit identical to `E` but with its parent at `D` instead of `C`.  Fortunately, the `--graft` option creates the hypothetical commit (so it's no longer hypothetical, I guess) and sets up the replacement.

Comment: That did the trick!  I came to the same conclusion about the replacement really needing to happen one level further down the graph, since we'd need the squashed commit to be the (virtual) merge-base - but hadn't wrapped my head around `--graft` yet.  As it turns out, we had already found a way forward using `git merge -s ours master` (i.e. ignoring the hotfix changes), but I'm going to accept your answer because it's exactly what I was looking for originally.  Thanks!