# Using Git, show all commits that exist *only* on one specific branch, and not *any* others

Tags: git

Given a branch, I'd like to see a list of commits that exist **only** on that branch.  In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others) we discuss ways to see which commits are on one branch but not one or more specified other branches.

This is slightly different.  I'd like to see which commits are on one branch but not on **any** other branches.

The use case is in a branching strategy where some branches should only be merged to, and never committed directly on.  This would be used to check if any commits have been made directly on a "merge-only" branch.

EDIT: Below are steps to set up a dummy git repo to test:

```
git init
echo foo1 >> foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -am "initial valid commit"
git checkout -b merge-only
echo bar >> bar.txt
git add bar.txt
git commit -am "bad commit directly on merge-only"
git checkout master
echo foo2 >> foo.txt 
git commit -am "2nd valid commit on master"
git checkout merge-only 
git merge master
```

Only the commit with message "bad commit directly on merge-only", which was made directly on the merge-only branch, should show up.

Comment: This question presumes all the merged-from branches are currently available on the repo, are never deleted once fully merged in, and maybe never merged with a fast-forward.  Let me know if I'm missing something, but it seems to me this is only workable for a relatively small set of allowed merge-from branches, so why not just use the `git log ^branch1 ^branch2 merge-only-branch` syntax?

Comment: The `git log ^branch1 ^branch2 merge-only-branch` requires listing out every single branch.  That can be avoided with some clever use of bash/grep (see my answer below), but I'm hoping git has some built-in support for this.  You're correct that it presumes all merge-from branches are remote (local only are as good as non-existant to other devs).  Using `--no-merges` omits any commits that were merged in and then had their original merge-from branch deleted, so this assumes the merge-from branches are kept around until they have been merged to a non-merge-only-branch (i.e. master).

Comment: Possibly related: [Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1710894/456814).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Courtesy of my dear friend [Redmumba](https://serverfault.com/users/52693/redmumba):

```
git log --no-merges origin/merge-only \
    --not $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin |
    grep -Fv refs/remotes/origin/merge-only)
```

...where `origin/merge-only` is your remote merge-only branch name.  If working on a local-only git repo, substitute `refs/remotes/origin` with `refs/heads`, and substitute remote branch name `origin/merge-only` with local branch name `merge-only`, i.e.:

```
git log --no-merges merge-only \
    --not $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/heads |
    grep -Fv refs/heads/merge-only)
```

Comment: I'm hoping someone else can provide a grep-less solution using only git, but if not, this feels pretty elegant.

Comment: Yes, elegant.  Use `git for-each-ref` to list every ref name in origin, and `grep -v` to omit the merge-only branch.  `git log` takes a `--not` option, to which we pass our list of all refs (except the merge-only branch).  If you have a more elegant answer to the problem, let's hear it.

Comment: Oh I'm sure it's the most elegant answer.  I'm only arguing it's a bit "wordy/complex" for true elegance. :-)  Did not mean to disparage your approach, sir!

Comment: I think that this, or something like it, is about the best you're going to get. There doesn't seem to be any more elegant way to specify "in any branch but this" in `git`.

Comment: The trailing `/*` in the `git for-each-refs` commands rely on not matching some existing file and not having `failglob` or `nullglob` set (*bash* options, other shells vary). You should either quote/escape the asterisks or just leave the trailing `/*` off (`git for-each-ref` patterns can match “from the beginning up to a slash”).

Maybe use `grep -Fv refs/remotes/origin/foo` (`refs/heads/foo`) to be more strict about which refs are eliminated.

Comment: It can be simplified if you just want to see commits present in one branch and not in another: `git log --no-merges B1 --not B2`, where B1 is branch which you're interested in, and B2 is branch you want to compare B1 to. Both B1 and B2 can be local or remote branches, thus you can specify `git log --no-merges master --not origin/master`, or even specify two remote branches.

Comment: Swearing is not allowed on SO. Please say "clusterfrick".

Answer (score 89):

We just found this **elegant** solution

```
git log --first-parent --no-merges
```

In your example of course the initial commit still shows up.

this answer does not exactly answer the question, because the initial commit still shows up. On the other hand many people coming here seem to find the answer they are looking for.

Comment: Since the initial commit on master still shows up, this doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This does not work on several repos where I tried it. The accepted answer does work.

Comment: This alone doesn't satisfy _“commits that exist only on that branch”_ condition— it shows the `initial valid commit`, which is part of both the `merge-only` and `master` branches.  However, if one goes through the effort of puttin the current branch name at the end followed by ^-prefixed branch name(s) that one knows the current branch stemmed off of, it solves half the problems (excluding things that were merged).  Ex: `git log --first-parent --no-merges merge-only ^master`

Comment: I'm not sure why this is upvoted so much, it doesn't appear to be pertinent to the question at all. It certainly doesn't provide the information that the poster was looking for.

Comment: This answer may not be perfect. But it's simple and certainly works to some extend. I find it useful to add the branch name - ie filter all commits belong to a given branch: `git log --first-parent --no-merges | grep <branch_name>`

Comment: Thank you. Best solution imo.

Comment: This answer will typically not work if you have say a `topic` branch off a `master` branch, and you want to know commits that are on `topic` *only* (all ancestors common to `master` will still show up). The reason this answer gets upvoted is certainly because the OP use case doesn't match the title of the question.

Answer (score 26):

```
git log origin/dev..HEAD
```

This will show you all the commits made in your branch.

Comment: @Prakash `origin/branchName` will point to head of remote branch AND `HEAD` will point to commitid of last local commit in that branch. So this will not work when you have used git push.

Comment: You can use this to compare another local branch. The --no-merges flag may also be handy to address the OP's original question.

Answer (score 22):

@Prakash answer works. Just for clarity ...

```
git checkout feature-branch
git log master..HEAD
```

lists the commits on feature-branch but not the upstream branch (typically your master).

Answer (score 11):

Maybe this could help:

```
git show-branch
```

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Comment: This is actually quite helpful.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/7623339/874188 for a more elaborate example and some related answers.

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
git rev-list --all --not $(git rev-list --all ^branch)
```

Basically `git rev-list --all ^branch` gets all revisions not in branch and then you all the revisions in the repo and subtract the previous list which is the revisions *only* in the branch.

After @Brian's comments:

From git rev-list's documentation:

`List commits that are reachable by following the parent links from the given commit(s)`

So a command like `git rev-list A` where A is a commit will list commits that are reachable from A inclusive of A.

With that in mind, something like

`git rev-list --all ^A`

will list commits not reachable from A

So `git rev-list --all ^branch` will list all commits not reachable from the tip of branch. Which will remove all the commits in the branch, or in other words commits that are only in other branches.

Now let's come to `git rev-list --all --not $(git rev-list --all ^branch)`

This will be like `git rev-list --all --not {commits only in other branches}`

So we want to list `all` that are not reachable from `all commits only in other branches`

Which is the set of commits that are **only in** branch. Let's take a simple example:

```
             master

             |

A------------B

  \

   \

    C--------D--------E

                      |

                      branch
```

Here the goal is to get D and E, the commits not in any other branch.

`git rev-list --all ^branch` give only B

Now, `git rev-list --all --not B` is what we come down to. Which is also `git rev-list -all ^B` - we want all commits not reachable from B. In our case it's is D and E. Which is what we want.

Hope this explains how the command works correctly.

Edit after comment:

```
git init
echo foo1 >> foo.txt
git add foo.txt
git commit -am "initial valid commit"
git checkout -b merge-only
echo bar >> bar.txt
git add bar.txt
git commit -am "bad commit directly on merge-only"
git checkout master
echo foo2 >> foo.txt 
git commit -am "2nd valid commit on master"
```

After the above steps, if you do a `git rev-list --all --not $(git rev-list --all ^merge-only)` you will get the commit you were looking for - the `"bad commit directly on merge-only"` one.

But once you do the final step in your steps  `git merge master` the command will not give the expected output. Because as of now there is no commit that is not there in merge-only since the one extra commit in master also has been merged to merge-only. So `git rev-list --all ^branch` gives empty result and hence `git rev-list -all --not $(git rev-list --all ^branch)` will give **all** the commits in merge-only.

Comment: Hm...not sure why, but this doesn't quite work.  Piping your command's output to `xargs -L 1 -t git branch -a --contains` shows plenty of false positives (commits that are in fact on other branches).  I tried with and without `--no-merges`.  Thanks for answering though!

Comment: Seems to work fine for me as far as I can see in a dummy git repo.

Comment: I've added steps to create a dummy git repo to help demonstrate the problem with your answer.

Comment: Ah, whoops. Upvoted this before I'd thought it all the way through. `git rev-list --all ^branch` will give you all commits that are not in `branch`. You are then subtracting that from the list that *are* in `branch`; but by definition, all commits that are not in `branch` are not in `branch`, so you're not subtracting anything. What jimmyorr is looking for are commits that are in `branch` but not `master`, nor any other branch. You don't want to subtract the commits that aren't in `branch`; you want to subtract the commits that are in any other branches.

Comment: @Brian - you are right. But the weird thing thing is, it is giving the expected results though! But updated the answer to use `--all` in place of `branch` and I think, this time it is valid :) So you can upvote :)

Comment: @manojlds Read my comment carefully. If you think about it, the `--not $(git rev-list --all ^branch)` in your command is doing nothing at all. You are finding all commits that are in `branch`, that are not not in `branch`; but not not in `branch` just means that they are in `branch`. Even if you update it to use `--all` instead of `branch`, you get the same result; you're just finding all of the commits in `branch`, not all of the commits in `branch` but not in any others.

Comment: @Brian - did you see my update? Now it is (all revisions ) - ( all revisions not in branch ) = revision in branch. Why wouldn't that work? git rev-list **--all** --not $(git rev-list --all ^branch)

Comment: @Brian, after the edit in your comment - the --not is part of the outer rev-list which has the list of all revisions. Subtract that with the revisions NOT in branch, you get revisions in branch.

Comment: `but not not in branch just means that they are in branch` - this is where you are wrong. The not is being applied universally to commits. all commits - (!branch) = branch commits. Right?

Comment: @manojlds "(all revisions ) - ( all revisions not in branch ) = revision in branch." Yes, that works to get all revisions in `branch`, but so does `git rev-list branch`. You're just writing `git rev-list branch` in a more complicated (and slower) way. It doesn't work to answer the question, which is how to find all commits in `branch` *that are not in any other branch*.

Comment: @Brian - see my response explaining the whole command with an example

Comment: This doesn't seem to work if your branch is in position that it could be fast-fwd'd when merged into another branch. So, if I use your example but don't perform the last three steps it will return the wrong answer. It returns both the commit on `merge-only` and the commit on `master`. Thoughts?

Comment: Thanks, this worked for me when i just have created a new branch and want to see only new commits on this branch. Can add `--online` for better  info

Answer (score 6):

This is not exactly a real answer, but I need access to formatting, and a lot of space.  I'll try to describe the theory behind what I consider the two best answers: [the accepted one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720575/1256452) and [the (at least currently) top-ranked one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7415282/1256452).  But in fact, they answer different *questions*.

Commits in Git are very often "on" more than one branch at a time.  Indeed, that's much of what the question is about.  Given:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I--J   <-- develop
```

where the uppercase letters stand in for actual Git hash IDs, we're often looking for *only commit `H`* or *only commits `I-J`* in our `git log` output.  Commits up through `G` are on *both* branches, so we'd like to exclude them.

(Note that in graphs drawn like this, newer commits are towards the right.  The *names* select the single right-most commit on that line.  Each of those commits has a parent commit, which is the commit to their left: the parent of `H` is `G`, and the parent of `J` is `I`.  The parent of `I` is `G` again.  The parent of `G` is `F`, and `F` has a parent that simply isn't shown here: it's part of the `...` section.)

For this particularly simple case, we can use:

```
git log master..develop    # note: two dots
```

to view `I-J`, or:

```
git log develop..master    # note: two dots
```

to view `H` only.  The right-side name, after the two dots, tells Git: *yes, these commits*.  The left-side name, before the two dots, tells Git: *no, not these commits*.  Git starts at the *end*—at commit `H` or commit `J`—and works *backwards*.  For (much) more about this, see [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).

The way the original question is phrased, the desire is to find commits that are *reachable from* one particular name, but not from *any other name* in that same general category.  That is, if we have a more complex graph:

```
               O--P   <-- name5
              /
             N   <-- name4
            /
...--F--G--H--I---M   <-- name1
         \       /
          J-----K   <-- name2
           \
            L   <-- name3
```

we could pick out one of these names, such as `name4` or `name3`, and ask: *which commits can be found by that name, but not by any of the other names?*  If we pick `name3` the answer is commit `L`.  If we pick `name4`, the answer is no commits at all: the commit that `name4` names is commit `N` but commit `N` can be found by starting at `name5` and working backwards.

The accepted answer works with remote-tracking names, rather than branch names, and allows you to designate one—the one spelled `origin/merge-only`—as the selected name and look at all other names in that namespace.  It also avoids showing merges: if we pick `name1` as the "interesting name", and say *show me commits that are reachable from `name1` but not any other name*, we'll see merge commit `M` as well as regular commit `I`.

The most popular answer is quite different.  It's all about traversing the commit graph *without* following *both legs* of a merge, and *without showing* any of the commits that *are* merges.  If we start with `name1`, for instance, we won't show `M` (it's a merge), but assuming the *first* parent of merge `M` is commit `I`, we won't even look at commits `J` and `K`.  We'll end up showing commit `I`, and also commits `H`, `G`, `F`, and so on—none of these are merge commits and all are reachable by starting at `M` and working backwards, visiting only the *first* parent of each merge commit.

The most-popular answer is pretty well suited to, for instance, looking at `master` when `master` is intended to be a merge-only branch.  If all "real work" was done on side branches which were subsequently merged into `master`, we will have a pattern like this:

```
I---------M---------N   <-- master
 \       / \       /
  o--o--o   o--o--o
```

where all the un-letter-named `o` commits are ordinary (non-merge) commits and `M` and `N` are merge commits.  Commit `I` is the initial commit: the very first commit ever made, and the only one that *should* be on master that isn't a merge commit.  If the `git log --first-parent --no-merges master` shows any commit *other than* `I`, we have a situation like this:

```
I---------M----*----N   <-- master
 \       / \       /
  o--o--o   o--o--o
```

where we want to see commit `*` that was made directly on `master`, not by merging some feature branch.

**In short, the popular answer is great for looking at `master` when `master` is meant to be merge-only, but is not as great for other situations.**  The accepted answer works for these other situations.

#### Are remote-tracking names like `origin/master` *branch* names?

Some parts of Git say they're not:

```
git checkout master
...
git status
```

says `on branch master`, but:

```
git checkout origin/master
...
git status
```

says `HEAD detached at origin/master`.  I prefer to agree with `git checkout` / `git switch`: `origin/master` is not a *branch name* because you cannot get "on" it.

[The accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5720575/1256452) uses remote-tracking names `origin/*` as "branch names":

```
git log --no-merges origin/merge-only \
    --not $(git for-each-ref --format="%(refname)" refs/remotes/origin |
    grep -Fv refs/remotes/origin/merge-only)
```

The middle line, which invokes `git for-each-ref`, iterates over the remote-tracking names for the remote named `origin`.

The reason this is a good solution to the original problem is that we're interested here in *someone else's* branch names, rather than *our* branch names.  But that means we've defined *branch* as something other than *our branch names*.  That's fine: just be aware that you're doing this, when you do it.

#### `git log` traverses some part(s) of the commit graph

What we're really searching for here are series of what I have called *daglets:* see [What exactly do we mean by "branch"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25068543/1256452)  That is, we're looking for *fragments within some subset of the overall commit graph*.

Whenever we have Git look at a branch name like `master`, a tag name like `v2.1`, or a remote-tracking name like `origin/master`, we tend to want to have Git tell us about that commit *and* every commit that we can get to from that commit: starting there, and working backwards.

In mathematics, this is referred to as [walking a graph](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/Walk.html).  Git's commit graph is a *Directed Acyclic Graph* or *DAG*, and this kind of graph is particularly suited for walking.  When walking such a graph, one will visit each graph vertex that is *reachable* via the path being used.  The vertices in the Git graph are the commits, with the edges being arcs—one-way links—going from each child to each parent.  (This is where [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/) comes in.  The one-way nature of arcs means that Git must work backwards, from child to parent.)

The two main Git commands for graph-walking are `git log` and `git rev-list`.  These commands are extremely similar—in fact they're mostly built from the same source files—but their output is different: `git log` produces output for humans to read, while `git rev-list` produces output meant for other Git programs to read.<sup>1</sup>  Both commands do this kind of graph-walk.

The graph walk they do is specifically: *given some set of starting point commits* (perhaps just one commit, perhaps a bunch of hash IDs, perhaps a bunch of names that resolve to hash IDs), *walk the graph, visiting commits*.  Particular directives, such as `--not` or a prefix `^`, or `--ancestry-path`, or `--first-parent`, modify the *graph walk* in some way.

As they do the graph walk, they visit each commit.  But they only *print* some selected *subset* of the walked commits.  Directives such as `--no-merges` or `--before <date>` tell the graph-walking code which commits to *print*.

In order to do this visiting, one commit at a time, these two command use a [*priority queue*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_queue).  You run `git log` or `git rev-list` and give it some starting point commits.  They put those commits into the priority queue.  For instance, a simple:

```
git log master
```

turns the name `master` into a raw hash ID and puts that one hash ID into the queue.  Or:

```
git log master develop
```

turns both names into hash IDs and—assuming these are two different hash IDs—puts both into the queue.

The priority of the commits in this queue is determined by still more arguments.  For instance, the argument `--author-date-order` tells `git log` or `git rev-list` to use the *author* timestamp, rather than the committer timestamp.  The default is to use the committer timestamp and pick the newest-by-date commit: the one with the highest numerical date.  So with `master develop`, assuming these resolve to two different commits, Git will show whichever one came *later* first, because that will be at the front of the queue.

In any case, the revision walking code now runs in a loop:

- While there are commits in the queue:

  - Remove the first queue entry.
  - Decide whether to print this commit at all.  For instance, `--no-merges`: print nothing if it is a merge commit; `--before`: print nothing if its date does not come before the designated time.  If printing *isn't* suppressed, print the commit: for `git log`, show its log; for `git rev-list`, print its hash ID.
  - Put some or all of this commit's *parent* commits into the queue (as long as it isn't there now, and has not been visited already<sup>2</sup>).  The normal default is to put in all parents.  Using `--first-parent` suppresses all but the *first* parent of each merge.

(Both `git log` and `git rev-list` can do *history simplification* with or without *parent rewriting* at this point as well, but we'll skip over that here.)

For a simple chain, like *start at `HEAD` and work backwards* when there are no merge commits, the queue always has one commit in it at the top of the loop.  There's one commit, so we pop it off and print it and put its (single) parent into the queue and go around again, and we follow the chain backwards until we reach the very first commit, or the user gets tired of `git log` output and quits the program.  In this case, none of the ordering options matter: there is only ever one commit to show.

When there are merges and we follow both parents—both "legs" of the merge—or when you give `git log` or `git rev-list` more than one starting commit, the sorting options matter.

Last, consider the effect of `--not` or `^` in front of a commit specifier.  These have several ways to write them:

```
git log master --not develop
```

or:

```
git log ^develop master
```

or:

```
git log develop..master
```

all mean the same thing.  The `--not` is like the prefix `^` except that it applies to more than one name:

```
git log ^branch1 ^branch2 branch3
```

means *not branch1, not branch2, yes branch3;* but:

```
git log --not branch1 branch2 branch3
```

means *not branch1, not branch2, not branch3,* and you have to use a second `--not` to turn it off:

```
git log --not branch1 branch2 --not branch3
```

which is a bit awkward.  The two "not" directives are combined via XOR, so if you really want, you can write:

```
git log --not branch1 branch2 ^branch3
```

to mean *not branch1, not branch2, yes branch3*, if you want to [obfuscate](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/obfuscate).

These all work by affecting the graph walk.  As `git log` or `git rev-list` walks the graph, it makes sure *not* to put into the priority queue any commit that is reachable from any of the *negated* references.  (In fact, they affect the starting setup too: negated commits can't go into the priority queue right from the command line, so `git log master ^master` shows nothing, for instance.)

*All* of the fancy syntax described in [the gitrevisions documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitrevisions) makes use of this, and you can expose this with a simple call to `git rev-parse`.  For instance:

```
$ git rev-parse origin/pu...origin/master     # note: three dots
b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb306
fc307aa3771ece59e174157510c6db6f0d4b40ec
^b34789c0b0d3b137f0bb516b417bd8d75e0cb306
```

The three-dot syntax means *commits reachable from either left or right side, but excluding commits reachable from both*.  In this case the `origin/master` commit,  `b34789c0b`, is itself reachable from `origin/pu` (`fc307aa37...`) so the `origin/master` hash appears twice, once with a negation, but in fact Git achieves the three-dot syntax by putting in two positive references—the two non-negated hash IDs—and one negative one, represented by the `^` prefix.

Simiarly:

```
$ git rev-parse master^^@
2c42fb76531f4565b5434e46102e6d85a0861738
2f0a093dd640e0dad0b261dae2427f2541b5426c
```

The `^@` syntax means *all the parents of the given commit*, and `master^` itself—the first parent of the commit selected by branch-name `master`—is a merge commit, so it has two parents.  These are the two parents.  And:

```
$ git rev-parse master^^!
0b07eecf6ed9334f09d6624732a4af2da03e38eb
^2c42fb76531f4565b5434e46102e6d85a0861738
^2f0a093dd640e0dad0b261dae2427f2541b5426c
```

The `^!` suffix means *the commit itself, but none of its parents*.  In this case, `master^` is `0b07eecf6...`.  We already saw both parents with the `^@` suffix; here they are again, but this time, negated.

---

<sup>1</sup>Many Git programs literally run `git rev-list` with various options, and read its output, to know what commits and/or other Git objects to use.

<sup>2</sup>Because the graph is *acyclic*, it's possible to guarantee that none have been visited already, if we add the constraint *never show a parent before showing all of its children* to the priority.  `--date-order`, `--author-date-order`, and `--topo-order` add this constraint.  The default sort order—which has no name—doesn't.  If the commit timestamps are screwy—if for instance some commits were made "in the future" by a computer whose clock was off—this could in some cases lead to odd looking output.

---

#### If you made it this far, you now know a lot about `git log`

Summary:

- `git log` is about showing some selected commits while walking some or all of some part of the graph.
- The `--no-merges` argument, found in both the accepted and the currently-top-ranked answers, suppresses showing some commits that *are* walked.
- The `--first-parent` argument, from the currently-top-ranked-answer, suppresses *walking* some parts of the graph, during the graph-walk itself.
- The `--not` prefix to command line arguments, as used in the accepted answer, suppresses ever *visiting* some parts of the graph at all, right from the start.

We get the answers we like, to two different questions, using these features.

Comment: `git log feature/add-login-page --not master` worked for my needs. Thanks for the info on `--not` prefix.

Comment: @marckassay: note that for your particularly simple need here, `git log master..feature/add-login-page` would suffice. The expression `A..B` usually means: `^A B`; `^A` means "not-A", with the "not" part applying only to `A` and not to `B` (while `--not A B` has the "not" part apply to both!). I say *usually* primarily because `git diff` is special: `git diff A..B` just means `git diff A B`.

Answer (score 2):

Another variation of the accepted answers, to use with `master`

`git log origin/master --not $(git branch -a | grep -Fv master)`

Filter all commits that happen in any branch other than master.