# Showing branch hierarchy at the command line?

Tags: git

I'm curious if there is a way to show branch hierarchy on the command line? For instance if I use `git branch`, instead of seeing output like this:

```
* master
joes_work
refactoring
experiment
```

You see output like this:

```
* master
    joes_work
    refactoring
        experiment
```

That way it's easy to see which branch a particular branch.. branched off of. Even if there's no specific command that outputs a tree structure, is there a command that outputs information on which branch came from which branch? I can use a perl script to format the output.

Comment: The question has nothing to do with the relationship between commits, branches only. You can have 5 branches pointed to unrelated commits which nevertheless form a graph in terms of their upstream branch. I don't think there's any way to get the answer from the git cli.

Answer (score 138):

sehe's solution looks great, here is another one that seems to contain similar information, formatted differently, it uses git log, so it contains commit information as well (ignore the branch names, I kind of messed them up!):

```
git log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --simplify-by-decoration

* ae038ad (HEAD, branch2-1) add content to tmp1
| * f5a0029 (branch2-1-1) Add another
|/  
* 3e56666 (branch1) Second wave of commits
| * 6c9af2a (branch1-2) add thing
|/  
* bfcf30a (master) commit 1
```

Comment: Yeah - I actually prefer this because it's more flexible but typing it from my phone would be a pain - plus most likely it would be a bit overkill to the OP

Comment: @sehe: you can make an alias of it. I have a similar git log alias that's reeeaaally nice, and I alias it to lg, so git lg.

Comment: Thanks ctcherry, this is really useful (second time I've needed it). I'd give you another up vote if I could.

Comment: Nice! I use `git config --global alias.tree 'log --all --graph --decorate --oneline --simplify-by-decoration'` which gives me `git tree`.

Answer (score 36):

I want to complete the answer of @ctcherry.

I like when I can also see the user who did the commit and the date, so this is the following line to use :

```
git log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit
```

However this is a pretty long line and difficult to memorize so you can use an alias. 
You just have to use this in your terminal :

`git config --global alias.lg "HERE GOES MY BIG LOG COMMAND LINE"`

---

To summarize copy and paste the line below on your terminal:

```
git config --global alias.lg "log --all --graph --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cgreen(%cr) %C(bold blue)<%an>%Creset' --abbrev-commit"
```

Then you will just have to use `git lg` to get your log history tree.

Example: 
[image]

[src](https://coderwall.com/p/euwpig/a-better-git-log)

Comment: Thanks for giving some _colour_ to an answer!

Comment: It's actually nice to use automatic coloring for the branch names as then you can differentiate between removes and local branches more easily: `%C(auto)%d%Creset`

Answer (score 33):

Try

```
git show-branch
git show-branch --all
```

Example output:

```
bash$ git show-branch --all
! [branchA] commitA only in branchA
 * [branchB] commitB
  ! [branchC] commitC only in branchC
---------------------
+   [branchA] commitA only in branchA 
 *  [branchB] commitB
  + [branchC] commitC only in branchC
 *+ [branchC~1] commitB-1 also in branchC
 *+ [branchC~2] commitB-2 also in branchC
+++ [branchC~3] common ancestor
+++ [branchC~4] more common ancestors
```

Comment: `git show-branch` shows *commits* in branch(es), not just a list of branches.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what I'm looking for. It seems to show commits in branches, but what I'm looking for is a way to see a tree view of all the branches.

Comment: The tree is drawn bottom up, not left to right, but it's there alright.  Where a twig seems to be broken, that's where a commit is missing from that twig.  Notice also how a commit could be missing from one branch even though it is otherwise identical to another branch, so just showing the branch names tends to oversimplify.

Answer (score 17):

Just type `gitk` command and press enter.

For me `gitk` is the easiest solution for this. Though it will not show you command mode, it will automatically populate a nice UI like this :

[image]

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most convenient answer if you are a visual person like I am. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

That's not how branches work from git's point of view. If I make some commits to branch `a`, create branch `b` from it, work there, and then do other work back on `a`:

```
A -- B -- D <-- a
       \
        \
          C <-- b
```

That's indistinguishable if you did it the other way around:

```
A -- B -- C <-- b
       \
        \
          D <-- a
```

The only way I can think of to find out from which branch certain branch originated is the reflog, but that's unreliable (entries older than 90 days are usually deleted).

Comment: Do you know if this applies to the files in .git/logs/refs/heads? There's a file in there for each branch, and the first line on the branch says which branch that branch came from.

Answer (score 0):

I just made a very simple CLI and put it to brew as I couldn't find anything similar, just a couple of lines in go: https://github.com/mucansever/gittree

Answer (score -3):

How about this alias for your `.gitconfig`:

```
[alias]
branch-tree = !cd "$(git rev-parse --git-dir)/refs/heads" && tree
```

You can also give options, depending on what your `tree` command supports, such as `-D` for timestamps.

Comment: This is just a crappy version of `git branch`. The question wants something that shows branch hierarchy - which branches a branch branches from, etc...