# Finding commits for only current branch that does not exist in other branches

Tags: git

So i have a merge path in the upstream as

branch1->branch2->branch3

Currently branch 3 has been forked by developers and is being merged to with new commits daily. Daily merges are being done from branch1,2 into branch 3. My question is, how can i do a "git log" to get commits from branch3 in the upstream that do not exist in branch2 and branch1. I want this to exclude those merges from branch 2 into branch 3 but still allow to show merges of developers merging into 3.2.0 from their forks. I have tried git log master..branch3 but that did not work (branch 2 was merged to master) so i was wondering if there is something i am missing

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using Git, show all commits that exist \*only\* on one specific branch, and not \*any\* others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5720343/using-git-show-all-commits-that-exist-only-on-one-specific-branch-and-not-a)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+list+commits+not+other+branches

Comment: I've was looking at that earlier and wasn't following the checked answer. Didn't know what that whole solution was broken down