# How can I find all commits that are in one branch but not in another using git?

Tags: git

I've two branches, *master* and *live*. *Master* is the development
   branch and contains commits that aren't ready to go into *live*.

- If a change is made in the *master* branch that needs to go into the
  *live* branch then they're cherry picked from *master* to *live*.
- Sometimes commits are made to the *live* branch that are then either
  cherry picked into *master* or merged into *master*.

What I want to be able to do is view all the commits that are in *master* than aren't in *live*, I've had a good search on here and Google and I was using this:

```
git log --cherry-pick --no-merges --oneline master...live
```

This worked until I merged *live* into *master*. But now it lists several commits that are in both.

So what is the correct command to view all commits that are in the *master* branch and not in the *live* branch?

Comment: Have you looked at `git cherry` (which is completely different from `git cherry-pick`)? I haven't played with it a lot, so I don't know how it works post-merge, but it is supposed to "find commits not merged upstream". I think in your case it would be `git cherry live master`.

Comment: I've tried that too and that sadly doesn't work either. It prints a similar list to the original command in the question.

Comment: The *correct* solution here would be to use branches rather than cherry-picks, IMO. But the `--cherry-pick` argument should do what you want it to, and certainly seems to in the quick test I just did. Can you reproduce this in a test repository so we can see what's different between my test and your problem?

Comment: how about `git log <layout options> master..live` (note the two dots instead of three), which will list all commits between where master points and where live points.

Comment: Did you maybe do a strange merge? Did you maybe cherry pick a commit from live into master that was already merged there?

Comment: I do not think there is a magical git command that is able to do this as parents in both branches might be different (and thus SHAs too). Because I work with gerrit code review I wrote a script that searches for commit-ids generated by gerrit (part of the commit msg) and try to look them up in the other branch.

Comment: me_and I need to use cherry picks to merge bug fixes from one branch into the other. Nevik the two dots generate the same output as git cherry (see comment in answer below). Chronial, I didn't cherry pick an already merged commit, however I will have merged a branch a few days after cherry picking a commit from it. gvd can you share the script?

Comment: @gvd – that’s not true. `git log --cherry-pick` is meant for exactly that: it does not compare commit SHAs, but diffs and thus identifies commits that introduced exactly the same change. Independent of parent commit, dates and commit message.

Comment: @Chronial you are right, I was unaware of this switch. Thanks.

Comment: Can you set up a small example repository demonstrating your case?

Comment: (You really should think about merges (from live to master) instead of cherry-picks.)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/different-commits-between-two-branches

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up solving my own problem using a short python script combining git patch-id and git log, the script can be found here https://gist.github.com/4565584

Comment: How can I run this script? I got this error:
`[User]$ python3 compare-git-branch.py -a main -b feature -t yesterday
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "compare-git-branch.py", line 33, in <module>
    branch1_lines = branch1_output.split('\n')
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'`

Answer (score 27):

You are very close. The correct command is:

```
git log --cherry-pick --oneline --no-merges --left-only master...live
```

from the log manpage:

> `--left-only, --right-only`
>
> List only commits on the respective side of a symmetric range, i.e. only those which would be marked < resp.  > by --left-right.
>
> For example, --cherry-pick --right-only A...B omits those commits from B which are in A or are patch-equivalent to a commit in A.
> In other words, this lists the + commits from git cherry A B. More precisely, --cherry-pick --right-only --no-merges gives the
> exact list.

Comment: Sadly that doesn't work either, that lists even more commits that I know are in both branches.

Comment: Can you show us the output of `git show **commit-id** | git patch-id` of two of these commits that are the same?

Comment: These are two commits which are identical (one is a cherry pick)
git show a0d2346 | git patch-id
71c61dadd2e31e3b17606c28e937668c9fb2b313 a0d2346cea23d823a63218d85dfb8ff567b3c678
git show c0a0579 | git patch-id
71c61dadd2e31e3b17606c28e937668c9fb2b313 c0a0579263f221e2113436ff844ac862df77b82e

a0d2346 appears in the output of the command in the above answer

Comment: mhh – what the output of `git cherry` suggest? Does git realize that the commits are duplicates there?

Comment: git cherry with no arguments outputs nothing, git cherry live master throws out 34 commits most of which I know are in both branches, git cherry master live throws out one commit which I know is in both branches.

Comment: At least the manpage Chronial posted documents that **patch-equivalent** commits are recognized. This should include cherry-picked commits (with different SHA) as I understand it.

Comment: The `git cherry` command prefixes every commit with a symbol – `+` or `-`, that shows if it’s an original commit or if it’s cherry picked from the other branch – are these symbols correct?

Answer (score 4):

`git log master ^live --no-merges`

Comment: That produces the same output as the above command (assuming I add  --oneline to your command)