# Create a patch with every commit in log output

Tags: git

I have a situation similar to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13858276/how-can-i-find-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-in-another-using-git). Currently this command shows me perfectly all the commits I need:

```
git log --cherry-pick --oneline --no-merges --left-only branchB...branchA
```

Now, I want to create a patch file with every one of the commits displayed in the above command. How can I do it?

Answer (score 2):

Try this. I hope it's not too late.

```
NUM=1
for commit in $(git log --cherry-pick --no-merges --left-only branchB...branchA --reverse --pretty=tformat:"%H")
do
  git format-patch -1 $commit --start-number $NUM
  ((NUM++))
done
```

`--reverse` forces `git-log` to push results in reversed order - from the earliest one to the latest one, `"%H"` it's format containing only commit sha1 hash. Hashes are being provided as a single (`-1`) commits to create patch from. `--start-number` with incrementing value causes creation of patch files in right order.

Comment: I had the same problem when was migrating to another repository and successfully created commit files. Unfortunately, I wasn't able to apply them.