# Git: commits are shown in git log even after cherry-pick

Tags: git, version-control

My goal is to show what is committed in branch A but not in branch B. I am aware of the existing commands as described in the 2 following threads:

[Different commits between two branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/different-commits-between-two-branches)

[Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)

However if I cherry pick commits from B to A, the cherry picks keep showing up in the various commands when I diff between A and B. Am I missing something basic here.

Following are the commands I tried:

```
git log --cherry-pick --pretty=format:'%Cred%h%Creset -%C(yellow)%d%Creset %s %Cred%cn%Creset %Cgreen(%cr)%Creset' --abbrev-commit --date=relative B..A

git cherry B A

git log --oneline A ^B --no-merges
```

All of them keep showing commits that were already cherry-pick'ed
This causes wrongly developers to think that commits are missing from one branch to another.

Thx in advance.

Comment: `cherry-pick` creates new independent (but similar) commits. Git cannot know if a commit was cherry picked or created manually.

Comment: `git cherry B A` does what you seem to want.  Perhaps you are looking for `git cherry B A | awk '/+/{print $2}'`