# How can I count number of commits between two branches?

Tags: git

Using the `git diff --shortstat my_branch master` is a great way to tell how many files changes and the insertions and deletions. I read the [git diff documentation](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff), but I couldn't find a way to tell the number of commits between `my_branch` and `master`. Does that exist?

Comment: are you asking for (#commits on master not on my_branch) + (#commits  on my_branch not on master) ?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I think you could try:

> git log --oneline mybranch ^master

For the exact count:

> git log --oneline mybranch ^master | wc -l

Should give you the information you want.

Comment: what is up with the `^` sign?

Comment: It means to select the log starting with mybranch and ending at and not including master.

Answer (score 40):

I found this to be much simpler:

```
git rev-list --count my-branch ^master
```

Comment: missing .. between branches as of git version 2.13.5 (Apple Git-94)

Comment: `..` not needed with git version 2.14.2 on Ubuntu Linux.

Comment: If you're already on `my-branch` you can use `HEAD` instead: `git rev-list --count HEAD ^master`

Comment: `my-branch ^master` is the same as `^master my-branch` and `master..my-branch`. This notation lists all commits which are in `my-branch` but are not yet in `master`. You can also use `master...my-branch` (which is the same as `my-branch...master` or just `...master` if you're currently on `my-branch`) which lists commits unique to `my-branch` and `master`, i.e. how much the two branches diverged.

Answer (score 25):

I could not get etech's answer to work, but this works for me on OS X:

```
git rev-list --count master..my-branch
```

`my-branch` can be omitted for changes on the current branch.

Answer (score 4):

Another option. The hashes/number are just examples

```
$ git checkout my_branch
$ git cherry master

+ 950b187c4b28844680df7008cfa3b348c1a46016
+ 109e427cbe84c3c8fc0ac2fbfb5120bcc2511933
+ 9bc217c0bcabbd6aa4ba88bbaaad23805994f90d
+ 74e054614a1bb1c442fbcf53926dcb910097321c
+ b34ae1ce8a58e0cbdbe1657ebca81a3036d7c72d
```

Will give a list of commit hashes that are in my_branch but not in master

```
$ git checkout my_branch
$ git cherry master | wc -l
5
```

Will give the number of commits that are in my_branch but not in master

Read more about git cherry [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/different-commits-between-two-branches)

Answer (score 0):

This gives me the number of commits I've made to `branch_being_merged_in` since branching from `branch_A`:

> git log --pretty=%H branch_A..branch_being_merged_in | wc -l