# Git: split pull request into smaller PR's based upon the new directories in the pull request

Tags: git, github, git-filter-branch

I have a monolith of a feature branch. Instead of one massive PR into master I would like to split it up into 3 prs.

Ideally I want to pull out some standalone code from the feature branch into a PR by itself. This code is in a new directory and isn't called into yet so it would be a relatively safe PR. However instead of just copying the directory and creating a single commit and PR I would like to retain all the commit history of the changes for the new PR.

Is this possible using Git?  I've looked into filter-branch but it seems like that is for splitting a repo into two, not for splitting a diff of changes into two (if that makes sense).

Comment: 3 years later and this problem persists. You still cannot easily move changes to certain files between branches. You have to wrap those changes in commits, yadda yadda yadda

Comment: Related, and answering the general question of how to break up a large Pull Request (PR), especially when squashing your commits is impractical due to one or more merges of `master` into your `feature_branch`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7566416/how-to-see-which-commits-in-one-branch-arent-in-the-other/60731900#60731900

Answer (score 23):

> is there a way to pull files out of a branch including their commit history into a new branch?

You pull a *commit*, meaning a whole repo into a branch, not just some files.

One good option would then be to reset the files you don't want to their content pre-branch

```
--x--x--x (master)
         \
          y--y--y (branch B1 with mixed work)
                 \
                  z (new branch B2, but with some files reset to master)
```

`B2` starts from `B1` and include the files you want, with their history.
But `B2` also includes other files from `B1` that you would like to be as `master`.

You can do (in `B2`) a `git reset --soft master`: a `git status` would tell you all the changes you need to do in order for your index to reflect master. Simply don't add changes that involves the files you want to keep by using `git restore -- path/to/file` ([`restore`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-restore) instead of [`checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), since [Git 2.23](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57066072/6309), Aug. 2019).
And don't commit. You just want to stage changes back to `master` for *some* files.

(See also "[Practical uses of `git reset --soft`?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5203535/6309)")

Once that is done, a `git reset --soft B2` moves HEAD back to `B2` (but with an index recording all the changes and deletions necessary to reflect master for the right files).

You can commit now, with the other files reverted to `master` and the files you want untouched, identical to `B1`, with their history intact.

Comment: @user3768149 note: once HEAD is moved to `master`, (`reset --soft master`), you can do simple `git checkout -- afile` for the other files you want to reset to `master`, and leave the files you want untouched. Moving back HEAD to `B2` would allow you to commit the "other files" content (which are now reflecting `master`)

Answer (score 11):

Github pull requests always concern a branch. If you want to "split a pull request", make sure it is split well-enough into commits, and then make a branch for each pull request you want to make and make sure each such feature branch has all the relevant commits.

It looks like a good strategy for you might be to create 3 branches next to your main branch, cherry-pick the relevant commits to each branch, delete them on main, and have main merge with each of the three branches. Then you could have a PR for each branch and shared history too.

Comment: Sorry I might not have been clear enough. I want to split a branch with a set of changes into multiple branches based upon a directory.  i.e. one way would be copy the directories only into a new branch off master and commit and make a PR but then it would lose all the commit history associated with the files in that directory. so is there a way to pull files out of a branch including their commit history into a new branch?

Answer (score 4):

This is my preferred solution, but in this case you will lose your git history. If you really want to keep it, you can simply copy-paste it into the commit message of each individual PR.

I normally go through the list of changed files and create a .patch file for each set of changes that belong in a separate PR. In this case, this would be a very simple way to separate changes by directory.

For example, the following would put changes to the README.md and users_controllers.rb files, and any files within the views directory into a match file, which could then be applied on the new branch. Then a new PR can be made.

First checkout the branch with the too-big PR, then

`git diff master head -- README.md app/controller/users_controller.rb app/views > first_group_of_changes.patch`

Comment: Few tips: You may exclude files with `':!<pattern>'`, such as `':!somedir/'` or `':!*.py'`, and you may add many exclusions to same command `':!like' ':!this'`. On Windows, use double quotes (`"`) instead of single quotes. And it makes life easier if you use `git diff --stat` to check the outcomes before creating the patches. And the applying process is `git apply some.patch`, after which you may create one or more commits.