# Check whether two GitHub branches are "even" w/o local git repo?

Tags: git, github

[How can I check whether two branches are "even"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31982954/how-can-i-check-whether-two-branches-are-even) describes how to check if two git branches are even. However, the answers rely on having the branched fetches and updated locally. As this is part of a script and the git repos are quite big, I do not want to fetch all the info for the branches.

How do I check if two branches on a GitHub repo are even w/o having local copy of the git repo?

Comment: This can't work: You want to compare info but not fetch the info? The only possibility I see is that you delegate the comparison to some system that already has the info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`git ls-remote`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-remote.html) will print the commit hashes for a remote repository for any ref that you pass it without downloading the complete history, e.g.

```
git ls-remote origin master v1.0.0
```

Could print:

```
cefe983a320c03d7843ac78e73bd513a27806845    refs/heads/master
f665776185ad074b236c00751d666da7d1977dbe    refs/tags/v1.0.0
```

From there, extract the hashes and compare them.

`ls-remote` doesn't even require a local Git repository; you can call it from anywhere as long as you pass it a valid "remote":

```
git ls-remote git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/git/git.git master v1.0.0
```

Comment: On the other hand, it *does* require a local repo, but that could just be `git init` and `git origin add origin <url>`, I guess.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice not necessarily, you can also do `git ls-remote url-to-repo ref` outside of a local repo. Thanks for asking, I will clarify this in my answer.