# commits missing in master from branch

Tags: git, github

I have a git repo in which some changes went into a release branch, but I've lost track if these are also in master branch.

Using git cherry I get only 3 commits as missing between master and the release branch.

However, on the github page if I go to the release branch, it says that it is 10 commits ahead of master (and even some commits behind master - but I don't necessarily care about that)!
How is that possible if on the console I get something else?
Thank you!

Comment: When you do cherry-pick, the commit-hash is changing from the original one, so you see `10 commits ahead of master...` message.

Answer (score 0):

> How is that possible if on the console I get something else

First, make sure to do a git fetch, in order to be sure to have the local history of the remote repo origin up-to-date.

Second, [`git cherry`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry), used to [see which commits in one branch aren't in the other](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566523/6309), works with the *content* of the commits, not their metadata (date, author, ...).
Whereas a branch comparison  (simple diff) compare the commits themselves, which have different SHA1. See "[git ahead/behind info between master and branch?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30720338/6309)" in order to get the same result locally.

Comment: So how would I find out then if I'm actually missing any commits in master that are in the release branch only?

Comment: @user3144292 you could rebase the `release` branch (or rather, a branch created at current `release` HEAD) onto `master`: the commits actually replayed on top of `master` are the one which were in `release` only. The other ones would *not* be replayed by the rebase.