# How to see git cherry output in reversed order with size limit?

Tags: git, github, version-control, commit, cherry-pick

I need to get the list of commits which have not been cherry-picked yet from other branch for specified time or size. Some of the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7566523/1084174) in Stackoverflow suggest to use command like,

```
git cherry main dev
```

However, when I run that above command, I see commit SHA are shown from the beginning of the project (~2/3 years backward) when I am only interested for the last month commits. I saw `git cherry` has no support for `--since`. **How can I see last months cherry-pickable commit list?**

**Is there any way around which can serve my requirement?**

Comment: According to `man git cherry` there does not seem to be such an option. There is a `limit` param, but I am afraid that will not help you much `git cherry main dev HEAD~100`

Comment: @tripleee yes it won't help either. Is it possible to pipe commits prior to run cherry?

Comment: Find a hash of the commit which is `--since $DATE` and supply the range to `git cherry`?

Comment: @0andriy how can I supply the range to git cherry?

Comment: @SazzadHissainKhan did you find any workaround for your request ?