# how to show the full commit message on the merged branch

Tags: git, git-flow, git-tower

I use the `git-flow` to develop my project

I often have hundreds of commit messages on the feature branch when developing.

But once merge the feature branch into develop branch,

I can only get one merged commit message and lose the hundreds of commit messages.

Is there any way to review the hundreds of committed messages on the feature branch after merged into develop branch.

Or to review the detailed commit messages on the feature branch is useless, so there is no way to review logs after you merge it ?

Can I achieve this on git-tower

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to list only the commits from the merged branch:

```
git log --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit mergedBranch ^mainBranch --no-merges
```

In your case: `feature/checkout_layout ^develop`.

(Based on "[Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4207176/6309)").

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what GUI tool you're using there, but what you're asking is certainly possible with the native Git CLI.  For example, this:

```
git log --date-order --all --graph
```

will give you what you want, i.e. commits on all branches.