# List changes in master since a branch was created

Tags: git, git-branch

A branch, called `mil-1` (for milestone) was created from master some time ago. There have been changes to master since this branch was created. I need to review them and merge some of them into the milestone branch.

After running `git fetch --all`, `git log refs/heads/master` lists the changes in master; and I know how to restrict them to a certain number of commits:

```
$ git log -1 origin/master
commit 5401cc7edf382183537a011632c422a491faea5b
Author: ********
Date:   Wed May 28 18:29:59 2014 +0530
```

But how do I restrict the output to only to commits done after the `mil-1` branch was created?

Comment: Possibly related: [Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1710894/456814).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `mil-1` hasn't been updated with the new commits made to `master`, then this is done using a simple commit range:

```
git log mil-1..origin/master
```

will show you all commits that exist in the `origin/master` that don't yet exist in `mil-1`.

See also [Pro Git § 6.1 Git Tools - Revision Selection: Commit Ranges](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Revision-Selection#Commit-Ranges).

Answer (score 1):

> But how do I restrict the output to only to commits done after the `mil-1` branch was created?

First you can use `git merge-base` to find the most recent commit the two branches have in common (which in your case is probably the commit that the branch was created from):

```
mergebase=$( git merge-base master mil-1 )
```

Then you can list all commits on the `master` branch since then:

```
git log $mergebase..master
```

Alternatively, you get the same result just asking for all commits between `mil-1..master`, which tells you all the commits which are in the history of `master` but not in the history of `mil-1`