# Git command to find commits made in branch that are not present in master

Tags: git, github

Looking for a git command which displays commits in a branch that are not merged to master yet, preferably with hash, date, author name and comment.

(This probably is a duplicate question but I couldn't find it on SO)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using Git, show all commits that are in one branch, but not the other(s)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To list commits that are not on `master` but only only on `branch`:

```
git log master..branch
```

It does not matter which branch is checked out, as you specify the range. Git will find the shortest route from `master` to `branch`, first going back on `master`, not printing the commits, and then listing commits when going forward in history towards `branch`.

The default format of `git log` contains all the data you wish to see. But I'd use the `--decorate` option too, to highlight branches and tags.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `^master` syntax to exclude commits visible from `master` (i.e. those merged to the master branch):

```
git log branch ^master
```

The format can be customized using the `--format` option, e.g. `--format="format:%H %ad %an %s"`

Comment: This solution also works, but difficult to remember that's why I chose the first one Thanks!!

Comment: @TarunGupta That's fine, the first one is used more often. Interestingly, I find this one easier to remember because it can also be used to view commits from several branches, and exclude several other branches: `git log branch1 branch2 ... ^exclude1 ^exclude2 ...`