# Managing long-lived branches in git / GitLab

Tags: git, branching-and-merging

Using `git` I have two long-lived branches: `master` and `develop`. Feature branches are taken from `develop` and then merged back into `develop` upon completion. Once we're happy we then merge the contents into `master`.

The "issue" I have is that `master` is now one commit ahead of `develop`. So the next branch that is taken from the tip of `develop` is one commit behind `master`. **Should I be concerned about this?**

I know this can be dealt with by performing a fast-forward merge into `master` (and therefore not creating the extra merge commit), but do I actually need to care about this? The reason I ask is because it feels like `develop` is going to become increasingly diverged from `master` upon each new `feature`->`develop`->`master` merge.

EDIT: I'm using GitLab / GitHub. The Merge Request / Pull Request feature necessitates a non-fast-forward merge.

Answer (score 2):

The only concern I'd have is why `master` needs to merge with `develop` at all. It should be a fast-forward. That suggests that there's things in `master` which are not in `develop`, like hot patches, and so you're not developing on top of everything which is in production.

You should have a situation like this:

```
  B - C   E - F   H - I
 /     \ /     \ /     \
A ----- D ----- G ------ J [develop]
        [master]
```

`master` is at D and has had a feature branch (B, C, D) previously merged in. `develop` is at J and has had two feature branches merged in. When you `git checkout master; git merge develop` it should be a simple fast-forward to J.

If you need a merge, it means `master` and `develop` have diverged. That probably means someone hot patched `master` and that patch hasn't gone back into `develop`. For example, the hot patch is E.

```
  B - C   E - F   H - I
 /     \ /     \ /     \
A ----- D ----- G ------ J [develop]
         \
          L [master]
```

Now when you `git checkout master; git merge develop` it will need to merge.

```
  B - C   E - F   H - I
 /     \ /     \ /     \
A ----- D ----- G ------ J [develop]
         \                \
          L -------------- K [master]
```

This will continue to happen.

This is more than a nuisance. It means `develop` never truly reflects the code that will run in `master` after the merge. You're developing and testing on a slightly different code base than what's in production. Eventually you'll merge a fully tested `develop` into `master` and production will break.

---

You'll probably want to look and see if there's any commits in `master` which are not in `develop` using [one of these techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1710894/using-git-show-all-commits-that-are-in-one-branch-but-not-the-others#4207176) and [cherry-pick](https://git-scm.com/docs/cherry-pick.html) them into `master`.

Alternatively, instead of merging you could `rebase` develop onto master, probably using `-p` to preserve your feature branches. Then merge (ie. fast forward).

That would go something like this, starting with the hot patched master...

```
  B - C   E - F   H - I
 /     \ /     \ /     \
A ----- D ----- G ------ J [develop]
         \
          L [master]
```

Then `git checkout develop; git rebase -p master`.

```
  B - C        E1 - F1  H1 - I1
 /     \      /      \ /      \
A ----- D - L ------ G1 ------ J1 [develop]
            [master]
```

Now you can fully test `develop` knowing it has everything it will have once "merged" into `master`.

Comment: Interesting and very helpful response - thanks!. What's your opinion when a non-fast-forward merge is required (perhaps due to GitLab's / GitHub's mechanism of managing Merge Requests / Pull Requests)?

Comment: @thehowler If you're using Github PRs for the develop -> master merge, that explains why you're always a commit behind. In that case that's fine, but you probably shouldn't be doing merges into production as a Github PR, you'll want finer control. An alternative to the rebase strategy above is to merge develop in, delete develop, tag the location (so you know it's a release), and create a new develop off master.

Comment: thank you for the clarification. My question should state this GitLab / Github constraint. I'll edit it and upvote you answer.

Comment: @thehowler Git(hub|lab) put no constraint on how you use Git. You can do the merge, or anything else you like, to the repo from the command line or any Git tool.

Comment: Yes - understood.