# Run git-clang-format on series of git commits

Tags: git, formatting, clang, clang-format

I have written a series of git commits, with awful code formatting.
Before I push them to github, I want to run `git-clang-format` on each commit, to get a nicely formatted code in my history.

Is there some combination of `rebase` and `git-clang-format` which will accomplish this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

That looks like a job for [`git filter-branch`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch), which can rewrite the commits you want. Since those commits are not yet pushed, changing their content (and, consequently their SHA1) is not a big deal.
And the effect is similar to what a rebase or cherry-picking would do, except you can run any command for each commit being replayed.

You can [run a `filter-branch` over the last few commits](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20974655/6309):

See "[**Reformatting Your Codebase with `git filter-branch`**](http://elliot.land/post/reformatting-your-codebase-with-git-filter-branch)", by [**Elliot Chance**](https://twitter.com/elliotchance)

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git-clang-format' -- <SHA1>..HEAD
```

Considering the [`git-clang-format` syntax](https://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/tools/clang-format/git-clang-format), you can apply it only on the changed files in each commit.
For instance, for `.cpp` files:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git-clang-format $(\
  git diff-index --diff-filter=AM --name-only $GIT_COMMIT |\
    grep .cpp) || true' -- <SHA1>..HEAD
```

---

Update 2017, with Git 2.14.x/2.15 (Q4 2017) you have an illustration:

See [commit 2118805](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2118805b929a47887f2ded218c95a5a274e36aa0), [commit 6134de6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6134de6ac1819aff8445490dfee3fb29966803c5) (14 Aug 2017) by [Brandon Williams (`mbrandonw`)](https://github.com/mbrandonw).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a36f631](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a36f631ad65a24070e5470784d6fd1f9be9bd72f), 25 Sep 2017)</sup>

Makefile: add style build rule

> Add the '`style`' build rule which will run `git-clang-format` on the diff between HEAD and the current worktree.
> The result is a diff of suggested changes.

```
.PHONY: style
style:
    git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git-clang-format || true' -- <SHA1>..HEAD
```

2022: as noted by [thakis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/551986/thakis) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43974371/run-git-clang-format-on-series-of-git-commits/45115656#comment136106786_45115656), [D117414](https://reviews.llvm.org/D117414) adds return code to `git-clang-format`, solving [`llvm/llvm-project` issue 53220](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/issues/53220)

Comment: `https://reviews.llvm.org/D117414` made `git-clang-format` exit with code 1 if any file changed. So you have to write `git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git-clang-format || true' -- <SHA1>..HEAD` now.

Comment: @thakis Thank you for this feedback: I have edited the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

I do this manually right now so the format does not mess up anything.  Example:  header reorganization is a possibility which can cause compile failures.

Steps start from latest commit. If you start at HEAD~# then the changes almost never unless they are atomic and unrelated.  git clang-format only changes the code you changed(and related code blocks) but not other non-touched code.

1. git clang-format HEAD~1 :result will be files changed.  Compile and verify.
2. git commit these new files as a temp commit.
3. git rebase -i HEAD~2
4. Change the new commit to be a "fixup" and finish the rebase.

(you can do this manually on a command line but for some reason I still do this with the editing).

You then repeat the steps for HEAD~2, HEAD~3 until you have finished working your way up to the chain.

Some Notes on this.  clang-format will change the same code over and over again in certain cases.  It has gotten much rarer but have to ignore them at times.

Comment: instead of creating a new commit and then squashing it, you can also update the HEAD directly by using `--amend.`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to apply clang-format **only to the changed lines** in each commit do the following:

```
# The first commit you want to edit.
# You can use the following command if it’s a child of origin/master.
export FIRST_COMMIT=$(git rev-list --ancestry-path origin/master..HEAD | tail -n 1)

git filter-branch --tree-filter 'git-clang-format $FIRST_COMMIT^' -- $FIRST_COMMIT..HEAD
```

This will do the following for each commit:

1. checkout the commit as it was in the original history
2. compute the diff to `FIRST_COMMIT`’s parent (e.g. `origin/master`).
   (NOTE: If you only were only to compute the diff to the current commits parent you may undo clang-format changes done on other commits!)
3. clang-format the affected lines
4. create a copy of the commit on top of the previous one