# Take history from one repository change author information and push to another repository

Tags: git, version-control, repository, git-history-rewrite

We have two repositories, 
1. source repository
2. target repository
When a commit comes in the source repository, I need to change the author name and author email then push to the target repository.

I have tried the solution from this [link](https://help.github.com/en/articles/changing-author-info)
but it seems to alter all the commits. I just need to change the latest ones only.

In the target repository, I need the commits with changed author name and email. After a particular commit reference.

Answer (score 0):

The `filter-branch` on the page you linked should work just fine, all you need to do is specify a range of commits, see [Running filter-branch over a range of commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250070/running-filter-branch-over-a-range-of-commits)

```
git filter-branch --env-filter '...' SHA1..HEAD
```

Comment: I have tried that but the history before the SHA1 remains the same as on source repo.