# Git filter-branch only on forked commits

Tags: git, git-filter-branch

I forked another repository, and then added a number of files to it. I occasionally merge in changes from the original repository to stay up-to-date.

I realized I have some files in my fork which should be removed, so I am trying to follow [1] to remove some files from my git repository. The source repo has thousands of commits, while I have a few hundred.

When I execute the command, it tries to search all the source commits as well, not just my fork commits, which would take hours instead of minutes.

`git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch filename.txt' --prune-empty @`

There are numerous merges from upstream in between.

```
master         A---B---C---D---E---F---G (HEAD)
                  /       /
upstream/master  H---I---J---K
```

[1] https://help.github.com/en/github/authenticating-to-github/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't looked at the `filter-repo` command yet, but you can feed `filter-branch` the exact list of commits you want to examine, everything after a `--` arg gets fed to the `rev-list` `filter-branch` runs to generate its candidates, e.g.

```
git filter-branch --index-filter "$myfilter" -- --first-parent HEAD
```

Comment: I used this in combination with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15250070/running-filter-branch-over-a-range-of-commits. I used the first commit from my branch to HEAD and it worked.

git filter-branch --index-filter $myfilter --prune-empty -- --first-parent sha1..HEAD

Answer (score 1):

I woyuld recommend to use the new tool [`git filter-repo`](https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo) which [replaces  BFG and `git filter-branch`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58251653/6309).

Note: if you get the following error message when running the above-mentioned commands:

```
Error: need a version of `git` whose `diff-tree` command has the `--combined-all-paths` option`
```

it means you have to [update `git`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/33618/16704).

---

See "[Path based filtering](https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo/blob/docs/html/git-filter-repo.html#EXAMPLES)":

```
git filter-repo --path file-to-remove --invert-paths
```

You can combine it with ref filtering: add first the URL of the original repo (that you have forked) to your local repo:

```
cd /path/to/local/clone/of/my/fork
git remote add upstream /url/original/repo
git fetch upstream
```

That way, you can limit the filtering to only your fork commits.
Here is an example assuming you have added commits on top of `upstream/master`.

```
git filter-repo --path file-to-remove --invert-paths \
  --refs upstream/master..<myBranch>
```

Comment: Would upstream/master..<myBranch> work even if there are multiple branches in between? I want to operate on A..G without touching H..K

Comment: @Prod It should, but test it on a cloned copy of the repo, to see if it does work as advertised.