# determining which merge commit caused a specific commit to be merged into my branch

Tags: git, merge, command-line-interface, commit

Given the following history:

```
master  A-B-C-D-E-F
             \
topic         G-H-I
```

What git command can I use to determine that `C` caused `G` to be merged into `master`?

Said another way, ignoring the branch name: "How can I determine which merge commit caused A to have G in its ancestry?"

Comment: Just a quick note that any programmatic solution to this will have to rely on the fact that `master` has only ever been merged into and never reset or rewritten, as Git does not keep track of which branch a commit was made to. (i.e. there is no universal solution)

Comment: Nevik, asked another way, "how can I determine which merge commit caused `A` to have `G` in its ancestry?" Forget about the branch name.

Answer (score 0):

`git merge-base G master` gives the common ancestor:

[Find common ancestor of two git branches](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549146/find-common-ancestor-of-two-branches)

I think this answers your first formulation, but I may not understand what you mean when you say "`C` caused `G` to be merged into `master`".

Comment: This reports `G` in my case. I'm looking for something that'll report `C`.

Answer (score 0):

You can walk forward in time from the first commit until you hit a merge commit that can reach the sought-after commit. By making the walk a first-parent walk we ignore all commits happening in side-branches.

Using the reachability test described in [How can I tell if one commit is a descendant of another commit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3005392/how-can-i-tell-if-one-commit-is-a-descendant-of-another-commit), the following example finds the first merge commit that introduced the commit identified by the contents of the `wanted` environment variable to the master branch:

```
for c in $(git rev-list --reverse --first-parent --merges master) ; do
  test $(git merge-base $wanted $c) = $wanted && echo $c && break
done
```

For Git 1.8.0 and later, the new `--is-ancestor` option can shorten the command somewhat:

```
for c in $(git rev-list --reverse --first-parent --merges master) ; do
  git merge-base --is-ancestor $wanted $c && echo $c && break
done
```