# Identify merge into master

Tags: git, version-control, merge

Given a commit *X* in the history of the master branch, I'd like to identify the merge where that commit got included into master. In other words, I want to find the maximal *i* such that *X* is an ancestor of `master~i`, i.e. the *i*-th ancestor of master along the first-parent chain. (This assumes that merges into master will have the previous master as first parent, which is usually the case afaik.) How can this be done efficiently?

### Example

To give an example, suppose I have the following history:

```
A - B - C - D - E - F - G - H
     \       \     /   /
      I -[J]- K - L - M
       \         /
        N - O - P
```

When I want to find out when `J` git merged into the master (upper line), I want the command to return `F`. Because from `H` the first-parent-only history is `H - G - F - E - …` and `J` is an ancestor of `F` but not an ancestor of `E`. Just looking for the nearest merge in the range `J..H` would be no good enough, since I don't want to find `K` or `L`. Both of these are not part of the first-parent-only history of `H` since `L` is the second parent of `F`.

Comment: A commit is a snapshot in time, so the commit X only occurs once, and cannot have been introduced by a previous commit. Likewise the `diff` from the previous commit (the particular changeset) is unlikely to have ever occurred before in its totality. Do you simply mean - find the first merge commit prior to X, while following the --first-parent mainline, so that you can see what was brought in at that point?

Comment: @PhilipOakley: No, that's not what I meant. I've edited my question, hope this clarifies what I'm after. Sure, a commit only occurs once, but it often enters master at a later time, namely not when it was committed but when it was merged. I want to find that merge. Which need not be the nearest merge, since that nearest merge may not be on mainline. So a simple `log --first-parent J..` tells me `J` diverged from master before `C`, and a simple `log --merges J..` (as you suggested in your answer) tells me `K` was the first merge after `J`, so neither of these answers my actual question.

Comment: added extra notes to my answer - if I had more time I'd try some code, but hopefully the suggestions will get you there.

Answer (score 2):

How's about:

```
git log --oneline --merges -1  [<rev range>]
```

This will list the first merge commit along the current branch, or from the commit X if you give that as the rev range. Review `git help log` to sweeten and serve.

---

Update to follow  clarified question

The extra technique is the use of

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <commit> <commit>
```

which will return true/false based on the ancestry (e.g https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526591/717355).

so first generate your list of first parent merges on master, either excluding commits reachable by the one in question, or using dates and the `--since=<commiter_date>` option. Then for each one in order (typically oldest first), check if your commit is an ancestor of the given merge commit. You could use the following bash script:

```sh
for merge in $(git rev-list --reverse --first-parent --merges "${commit}"..master)
do if git merge-base --is-ancestor "${commit}" "${merge}"
   then git show -s "${merge}"
        break
   fi
done
```

Comment: Thanks, this ancestry check is useful, even though I'd still need to loop over candidate commits, which I'd rather avoid. Timestamps may be misleading in some setups, I think, since they can be tinkered with or broken due to incorrect clock settings. So I'd suggest a reachability-based criterion there. I've included some code into your post, hope you don't mind. Personally I'd drop the `log --oneline` part (since it doesn't answer the question) and the `--since` part (since I think the alternative is better), but it's your post, and I didn't want to interfere too much. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I had a few RTFM moments of delving and you may find `git rev-list --first-parent --merges -- reverse <commit>..master` to your liking. Just take the first commit given ( ` | head -1` ) (note that `--max-count=` does not appear to work as `--reverse` is applied last).

Comment: Isn't that essentially the comment I suggested to generate candidates? Anyway, `--max-count` wouldn't be appropriate since there may be merges to master before the one I want but which are not reachable by the commit I input. In my example above, `C` might have been a merge of some other feature branch, and would be printed first. So I can't use this as the sole command to find my solution.

Comment: @MvG, Now I look, yes it is similar. I think it is that more revision limiters were needed. The rev-list order (including the double dot notation J..H) should guarantee that the first in the list (reversed) is the oldest that it could be that is both a merge and on the first parent chain (of master !), which I think was the request. Even if `C` is a merge its not in the J..H range. The max count can be confused as it could depend on reverse, or not, but it looks like it is applied *before* the reverse. Still, its a useful exercise in building Git understanding!

Comment: No, `C` *is* in the `J..H` range. That range is equivalent to `^J H`, i.e. the set of all commits reachable from `H` which are not reachable from `J`. Which is the case for `C`. I tried it (with the above example and without the `--merges` switch).

Comment: @MvG Oops. Yes you are right. Total brain fade. Especially as I've just submitted some documenation patches to update the git revisions pages! Do you have a public repo with that example in it?

Comment: No public repo, no real scenario with that exact history. But [these commands](https://gist.github.com/gagern/5b7b47b1103b0b32a7f6559cd3229f27) can reproduce the toy example. Nice set of patches, though I hate viewing them through mail archive. I miss Gmane…

Comment: @MvG, Try adding `--ancestry-path` (boy those manuals can be hard work) and https://public-inbox.org/git/ for the gmane replacement (can search by old gmane id numbers)

Comment: Sounds promising, but alas … `--first-parent` and `--ancestry-path` together give me an empty list of revisions. This might even be considered a bug, since I see no obvious semantic reasons they would have to be mutually exclusive.

Comment: See my https://gist.github.com/PhilipOakley/58f344f910e50b72f5a8a2bd55b6c175 which extends your example - looks like there is an option conflict between first parent and ancestry - I've posted it to the git list.

Comment: Links to your post for future reference: [mail archive](https://www.mail-archive.com/git@vger.kernel.org/msg101884.html) or [public inbox](https://public-inbox.org/git/2FA1998250474E76A386B82AD635E56A@PhilipOakley/). Thanks for asking. From the first answer I begin to understand the technical difficulty, but I think there should be a way around that. If I can put that into words, I'll likely post about it.