# How to programmatically determine whether a commit is in the current checkout

Tags: git

I want to programmatically determine whether a commit is in the git current checkout or not.

I just need a nonzero exit status, not other output.

I found this work around:

```
git log | grep -q 5bbfb3512b0ab900a66f70104bd0e052a66a699a
```

But this does not work 100% reliable. There could be a commit message which contains the string "5bbfb...".

Is there a solution without unix pipe and grep?

Comment: Specifically, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526591/1615903). You would use HEAD as `<descendant-commit>`

Answer (score 3):

You can simply not output the message - do like so:

```
git log --format=format:%H | grep -q <sha1 here>
```