# Git: Checking if a revision is among ancestors

Tags: git, revision

How do I check if a revision is among the ancestors of a commit. Is this done with rev-list?

**TL;DR**
I am looking for the omition of a recently added line of code and a git bisect ends up suggesting very distant revision that doesn’t share ancestry and with the revision that add that partical line of code (but also is merged). So to qualify as a bad bisect the partical line of code must have once been added before.

Comment: Do you mean ancestors rather than parents?

Comment: Yup, I was uncertain of the particular wording so I changed it to parents. But am I suppose a three- or four-way merge commit has multiple parents. So ancestry is better.

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/3005392/24874

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <ancestor> <descendant>
```

This command has an exit code of 0 if `ancestor` is an ancestor of `descendant`, otherwise returns 1.

Comment: So it wasn’t even rev-list. Thanks!

Comment: Would you know if it’s possible to bisect a straight line of ancestry? Looking at the documentation it doesn’t say anything about it. https://git-scm.com/docs/git-bisect

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "straight line of ancestry". Could you explain?