# Revert specific git commits and all subsequent commits that depend on them

Tags: git

I'd like to revert every commit K if and only if:

- K is one of two specific commits I want to reverse
- or, K depends on one or more of these commits I want to reverse

For background, I'd like to have a local copy of Flutter that reverses [these changes](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/50252).

Comment: A commit is not a “change”, and there is no sense in which one commit “depends” on another. So the whole question is meaningless.

Answer (score 1):

You can tell if one commit (one of the two you want to revert) [is an ancestor of another](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13526591/6309)

```
git merge-base --is-ancestor <maybe-ancestor-commit> <descendant-commit>
```

So list every commits of every branch and:

- if none of your 2 commits are ancestor of a branch HEAD, discard the branch
- if they are, start enumerating commit from that branch

You might consider soft resetting that branch to before those commits: the index would be at the desired state: you can add and commit that index as one new commit which would reverse anything done since those commits (ancestors of a given branch)