# How Do I Prune The Server reflog From Bitbucket?

Tags: git, bitbucket, bitbucket-server

This question is about Bitbucket server (where I have admin) and not the cloud offering.

I have mistakenly pushed a branch to the wrong project and merged it to an integration branch with a pull request.

The commit isn't sensitive data per-se but it is something that the project team shouldn't have visibility on.

I have deleted both branches on the remote, however, the commits are still visible from the UI.

The merged pull requests view shows the commits involved and allows you to click on them to see the details, even though the commits no longer exist in the repo.

I am assuming that this is Bitbucket reading the reflog.

How do I prune the reflog from the server, or better yet, remove the merged pull request?

Comment: _"even though the commits no longer exist in the repo."_ - this isn't true based on the previous statement. It's not reading the reflog. The commits are still reachable by another branch or tag.

Comment: You'd think so but no.

Comment: I do think so. The “removed” commit is still reachable. https://stackoverflow.com/q/3005392/989920