# What should 'git log ^X' show?

Tags: git, logging

```
$ git log --oneline
05f1c3b master: Modified 1.txt
f7433e0 Updated by master
e30dff9 Modified 1.txt
82ebf7a Modified 1.txt
cbb2785 master: Added 4.txt after rebase branch was created
980a5d6 b1: Added 1.txt
badc046 Resolved merge conflict
47a2d78 Mods by b2
c3eb61e Added by b1
9378e3d 1ST commit
```

The following shows nothing:

```
$ git log ^47a2d78
```

I thought it should show all commits from badc046 up, since these are not reachable from 47a2d78.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`^hash` means "Exclude commits that are reachable from (i.e. ancestors of) ."

Therefore:

```
git log ^47a2d78
```

translates to "show log for all commits excluded by hash 47a2d78". This doesn't match any commits. If you want to show all commits after `47a2d78` you must use `log ^47a2d78 HEAD`, or, more easily:

```
git log 47a2d78..HEAD
```

Comment: Cue the usual links to "positive refs" and "negative refs" (http://stackoverflow.com/a/850695/6309), and revision lists (http://stackoverflow.com/a/53573/6309). +1

Comment: Now that you confirmed it returns nothing, I realized that I misinterpreted the behavior, or rather expected git to "read my mind;" by law of negation, I'd thought git would be able to imply that I wanted to see commits NOT reachable from 47a2d78. Obviously, that is not possible since I did not specify that.

Answer (score -1):

If you want a log over a range of commits you can do:

```
git log HEAD...47a2d78
```

Comment: `^hash` means "not reachable from hash". `hash^` means "parent of hash"

Comment: I know that, but in this context it means nothing

Comment: i removed the explanation as it's specific to git log